# Gap between gather and hash join output in terms of plan rows

Tags: postgresql

I run a very simple query as an example

```
explain (ANALYZE) SELECT * from imdb.q1a_info_type natural join imdb_int.movie_info_idx
```

The result plan is

[image: plan]

I check the "plan rows" field on gather and "Hash Inner Join", which has 12213 and 7184 respectively (see below for the full plan). For this simple plan, I expect they are the same because my understanding on Gather is to combine all possible subplan output together, e.g., in bushy plan case. I don't understand why there is a gap in this example? Which number is more accurate estimate for the output size?

Thanks!

```
postgres=# explain (ANALYZE) SELECT * from imdb.q1a_info_type natural join imdb_int.movie_info_idx;
                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1002.42..18659.44 rows=12213 width=8) (actual time=122.149..122.247 rows=250 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 1
   Workers Launched: 0
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.43..16438.14 rows=7184 width=8) (actual time=121.936..121.972 rows=250 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (movie_info_idx.info_type_id = it.info_type_id)
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on movie_info_idx  (cost=0.00..14224.85 rows=811785 width=8) (actual time=0.006..59.001 rows=1380035 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=2.41..2.41 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
               ->  Seq Scan on info_type it  (cost=0.00..2.41 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((info)::text = 'top 250 rank'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 112
 Planning Time: 0.145 ms
 Execution Time: 122.273 ms
(13 rows)

Time: 122.885 ms
```

Comment: Looks weird at first glance, but without seeing the whole plan, it is gard to say more. `FORMAT text` please, no JSON.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have updated the full plan in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gather is reporting all expected rows, while the Hash Join is reporting the rows expected only by one of the parallel workers.  It is not exactly half, because the planner assumes work will (by chance) not be distributed exactly equally between the workers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the full plan above. It seems like I only have 1 worker, which IIUC doesn't fit the answer here.

Comment: The leader participates in the plan, but is not counted as a worker.  So '1 worker' means 2 processes doing work.  I wish they had chosen a different terminology here.  It actually didn't launch any workers, but the plan expected values reflects the intentions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The plan is full of surprise: by looking at the plan, I'm not sure who is contributing to the rest of 5029 rows (12213 - 7184). Is it common just assume 5029 rows is also contributed by hash join, i.e., it's weird to me that the plan doesn't list another hash join with "rows=5029" as estimate.

Comment: No one is contributing them.  You are looking at *expected* values.  They don't exist anywhere, they are just planning tools.  If one is expected to have 7184 and the other 5029 due to some expectation of uneven workload, then the worst-case one is the one that gets used for costing the overall plan, and that is the only one shown